# Meteor blaze, Use helper / variable in Content Blocks (contentFor)

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, iron-router, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have a template (navBarContent) that I is passed a "title" when I insert it.
I am then able to access {{title}} within that template, but it is not possible to access it within a {{#contentFor}} block embedded in the navBarContent template:

```
<template name="map">
   {{>navBarContent title="MAP"}}

   ... other content ...
<template>


<template name="navBarContent ">
    {{title}}

    {{#contentFor "headerTitle"}}
        <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

I already tried to "forward" the title:

```
<template name="navBarContent ">
    {{title}}

    {{#contentFor "headerTitle" title="MAP"}}
        <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

which produces the following error:
First argument must be a function, to be called on the rest of the arguments;

EDIT:

Ok. I think the data scopes are a the following:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> yield "headerTitleRenderedInLayout"}}
    {{> yield}}               
</template>

<template name='map'>
    {{> yield "headerTitleRenderedInTemplate"}}
    {{>navBarContent title="PARAMETER_TITLE"}}
</template>

<template name="navBarContent">
    {{title}}   <!-- output: PARAMETER_TITLE -->

    {{#contentFor "headerTitleRenderedInLayout"}}
        <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1> <!-- output: LAYOUT_DATA_TITLE -->
    {{/contentFor}}

    {{#contentFor "headerTitleRenderedInTemplate"}}
        <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1> <!-- output: TEMPLATE_DATA_TITLE -->
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

Above outputs are produced when I use the following router options:

```
Router.route('/map', function () {
    this.layout("layout", {
        data: function() {
            return { title:  "LAYOUT_DATA_TITLE" }
        }
    });

    this.render('map', {
        data: function() {
            return { title:  "TEMPLATE_DATA_TITLE" }
        }
    });
});
```

My app has a navbar that is defined in my main layout and I therefore need to set the datacontext for the layout in my route. So far so good, but I want to set that data context based on the value that I pass via:

```
{{>navBarContent title="PARAMETER_TITLE"}}
```

This is just a cosmetic thing, because I prefer to define my navbar content in the different templates rather than the routes.

Comment: Why are you passing data to `defaultNavBar` in the template? It should work when you use Iron Router to provide the data context: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data.

Comment: Because I don't call defaultNavBar via IronRouter. It is used within another template. the route goes to:

`<template name="map">
    {{>defaultNavBar title="MAP"}}
    .... other content ...
</template>`

Comment: Are you passing another data context to the `map` template in the `route` function?

Comment: No I don't pass any data context:

`Router.route('/map');`

Comment: I think it only works when you pass `{ title: 'MAP' }` as data context in the `route` function because Iron Router handles the rendering of the `contentFor` block.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried 

`Router.route('/map', function () {
    this.render('map', {data: function() {return { title: 'MAP' }}});
});`

without success

Answer (score 0):

It works when you pass the data context to the `render` function because Iron Router handles the `contentFor` block:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  this.render('map', {
    data: function() {
      return { title: 'MAP' }
    }
  });
});
```

Then the following template shows *MAP* twice:

```
<template name="map">
  {{> navBarContent }}
  {{> yield 'anotherBlock'}}
</template>

<template name="navBarContent">
  <div>
    In "map": {{title}}
  </div>

  {{#contentFor 'anotherBlock'}}
    <div>
      In contentFor: {{title}}
    </div>
  {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems that we're getting closer. I can pass the data context as long as the {{> yield}} is within the map template. unfortunately, the navbar is defined outside the map template. I.e. the contentFor refers to an element that is not part of the map data context.

Comment: Can you add more of your code to the question? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Where exactly is the data defined?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to pass the title like this because the data context built from the template arguments is always replaced by Iron Router.